# ifconfig never shows current IP address?

Tags: linux, ifconfig

I wish to know my current IP address (as the world sees it) via linux command line. I used ifconfig but it doesn't display the same ip address as is displayed on the website ip-details.com.

is there a way to get the current IP address from command line in linux?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find your external IP use the following command

> $ **dig myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com +short**

This would give your IP as seen by a website

**dig** command is a DNS lookup utility.
DIG (domain information groper) is a flexible tool for interrogating DNS name servers.
It performs DNS lookups and displays the answers that are returned from the name server(s) that were queried

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a VM (or) you are trying ifconfig from machine directly connected to internet ?

If you are trying from a VM it will not show. You have to try at host machine

Comment: my laptop is directly connected to the internet.

Comment: curl ifconfig.me
lynx -dump ifconfig.me | grep 'IP Address'

By this way you can directly get IP address details